# Custom check box in css not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I am newbie to CSS and jQuery . I tried to customize the check box and but isn't working . Can you please debug this .

Here is my code:

```css
.checkbox-custom{
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;   
}
.checkbox-custom, .checkbox-custom-label{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.checkbox-custom-label {
    position: relative;
}
.checkbox-custom + .checkbox-custom-label:before{
    content: '';
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.checkbox-custom:checked + .checkbox-custom-label:before {
    content: "\f095";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    background: rebeccapurple;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input id="checkbox-3" class="checkbox-custom" name="checkbox-3" type="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox-3"class="checkbox-custom-label">Third Choice</label>
```

And my output looks like ,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcSYs.png

Can anyone help me to debug this .

Comment: This maybe caused by IE.It looks right in chrome.

Comment: From the looks of it, the font awesome font isn't loading properly. If you go into the console, do you see any errors for missing files? You may also want to use ::before instead of :before (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your checkbox has a rectangle inside it instead of an icon is that you're using Font Awesome without loading it. Your browser sees the special U+F095 character, but it doesn't know where to find the icons, so it draws a box instead.

While [there are several ways to load Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/), the easiest is to add this line of code to your site's `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Here's a version of your snippet with that line added:

```css
.checkbox-custom{
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;   
}
.checkbox-custom, .checkbox-custom-label{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.checkbox-custom-label {
    position: relative;
}
.checkbox-custom + .checkbox-custom-label:before{
    content: '';
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.checkbox-custom:checked + .checkbox-custom-label:before {
    content: "\f095";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    background: rebeccapurple;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<input id="checkbox-3" class="checkbox-custom" name="checkbox-3" type="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox-3"class="checkbox-custom-label">Third Choice</label>
```